# find enabled protocols

Tags: t-sql

Is there a magic TSQL command which can show me the enabled or disabled SQL server protocols?
I thought it is select * from sys.endpoints but the state_desc field indicates "started" even for the protocols (which i know from "configuration manager") which is disabled.
any comments?
version: 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm interesting.  I've done a quick search and the closest I can find is [Enabling TCP/IP protocol through t-sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065328/enabling-tcp-ip-protocol-through-t-sql-script) which may set you on the right track.  From the documentation you can create and manage endpoints from within T-SQL but to enable the protocol then that is a registry setting done with configuration manager.  Which seems to make sense from a security view.